# Merge AVI-files without recoding in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: video, osx-lion, avi, merge

Is there a (at best free) solution to merge AVI-Files in Mac OS X Lion without the need to recode them? (Until Snow Leopard I used D-Vision 3, which won't run on Lion because it's PPC.)

Comment: By "merge", do you mean combine in sequence?

Comment: Also, we need to know the video format (motion JPEG? H.264?) to know whether this is possible.

Comment: @Mechanical: Yes, by merge I mean join them seamlessly in sequence. We can take as granted, that all files share the same framerate, codec and resolution. Used codec is mainly following the MPEG-4 standard such as Xvid. In fact it is possible as it was before Lion as well as it is with Windows. I'm looking for a tool that also runs on Lion.

Comment: In general, `ffmpeg` the tool for this.

Comment: I started the bounty only because @[w00t's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/318640/322700#322700) is *[godsend](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/setting-a-bounty-on-someone-elses-question-to-acknowledge-a-great-answer)* — it probably saved me few $/€'s worth of actual money; and it *would* had saved a lot of time & effort if I just had stumbled on it earlier…

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To make your copy of avidemux2.app work, simply open the application bundle (show package contents in finder) and remove the files libxml.2.dylib and libiconv.2.dylib from the Contents/Resources/lib folder.

This will make avidemux2 use the versions that ship with Lion and which seem to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, good information. Did not know I could delete them instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 17):

This works for me:

```
cat part1.avi part2.avi part3.avi > tmp.avi && mencoder -forceidx -oac copy -ovc copy tmp.avi -o output.avi && rm -f tmp.avi
```

Then output.avi should not only have the whole content but also have the indexes recalculated so the whole movie plays.

Comment: Genius.  And worked for me as well.

Comment: NB: The command line is quite long so be careful when copying it.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Excellent answer.

Comment: -bash: mencoder: command not found. Download ffmpegXbinaries20060307.zip unzip and then copy mencoder to /usr/local/bin and then above works wonderful. THANKS!

Comment: @westondeboer If you've got macports installed, `sudo port install mplayer`

Comment: Since mencoder can take multiple input arguments, I'm not sure why you would need to cat the files.

Answer (score 2):

Avidemux is an open source tool for editing/combining videos, and there is a Mac port:

http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. Avidemux does not support Lion at the moment. Avidemux uses a lion-incompatible version of the library libiconv.2.dylib. I got it working by replacing the library with a patched version from GnuCash: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=192432

Answer (score 1):

Try this Lion-compatible Version of D-Vision 3: 
[D-Vision 3 (Intel)](http://rapidshare.com/files/1894127269/D-Vision_3__Intel_.dmg)

Comment: Where did you get this version from? I'm not that comfortable with downloading programs from unknown sources.

Comment: Actually the author's site has a universal binary: http://www.objectifmac.com/dvision.php

Comment: @w00t: You're right. In fact the D-Vision main app works on Lion, while joining AVIs with D-Vision does not. You can start it, select the tool to join AVIs, select your AVI-files and start the task. I checked "delete source files when task is finished" (as always) and then I got the Rosetta-error and also lost my source-files.

Comment: @Chris: actually I just copied the universal-binary-files from the newest [D-Vision 4 beta](http://www.objectifmac.com/download/DVision4alpha8.zip) into the old D-Vision 3 App-Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

D-Vision will work with OS X Lion. Just use `mencoder` and not the default `avimerge`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download newest version of ffmpegX.
2. Right click “Show Package Contents”
3. Copy avimerge located in **Contents > Resources > avimerge**.
4. Paste the avimerge file in the same location within D-Vision.app file. To do this, right click “Show Package Contents” at the "D-vision.app" icon and paste it in "Contents > Resources".

D-Vision will then work a treat in Lion OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that requires absolutely no additional software. If you have OS X, you can do this.
Open Terminal and do this:

```
cat /path/to/part1.avi /path/to/part2.avi > /path/to/where/you/want/whole.avi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? You'll have to be more specific if you want some help.

Comment: This is great accept it doesn't work for me either.... I end up with only the first video in the output file (Mountain Lion)

Comment: This would probably only work for files that don't require any kind of header. To my knowledge, .avi files have a header so basically, this would only append the 2nd .avi file to the end of the first but the header information won't be there for it to be played.

Comment: The output file has the size of the combined input files, but only the first video file plays.  The avi player ignores the rest of the data.